# comparison with expression using javascript

Tags: javascript

here is my code

```
   function isDepositGreaterThanAvailable(){
   var deposit=$("#total").val();
   var available=$("#availableCash").val();

   if(deposit>available){
       $("#total").val(0);
       var msg = {
           "class": "com.docu.common.Message",
           "messageBody": ["Deposit must be less than or equal to Available Cash"],
           "messageTitle": "Message",
           "type": 2
       }
       MessageRenderer.render(msg);
       return false;
   }

   }
```

if `deposit` is greater than `available` then an error message shows.but when `deposit` is `smaller` than available,it shows error too.please help me to solve it.

Comment: What are the contents of the `total` and `availableCash` text fields? Maybe you are comparing the contents as strings?

Answer (score 2):

When you get a value out of an input element using jQuery `.val()`, it will always be a string. It doesn't matter that the input element is type="number". The JavaScript value is a string. Use the following if condition:

```
if(parseInt(deposit) > parseInt(available))
```

**EDIT:**
As pointed rightly by @nnnnnn, you might want to use [`parseFloat()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) as you are dealing with currency.

Comment: I don't think you want to use `parseInt()` on money values.